# In python , not able to send GET request if api url is in csv file

Tags: python, api, get, request

I am not able to send get request using pythons, giving api url through csv file and there is some condition in csv if they fulfill then this api run ,no response data is found in terminal on run

```
with open('xyz.csv', mode='r', newline='') as csvFile :
    reader= csv.reader(csvFile)

    for col in reader:
        if col[2].upper() == "Y" and col[9].upper() == "Y":
            r = requests.get(col[6],headers=headers)
            resp = json.loads(resp)
        elif resp.status_code == 200:
          print(resp.content)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Your print **will not** run if the request was correct because it's in a wrong `if` block!

When the first `if` is executed, your `elif` will not be entered (that's how if's work!). That means, you requests is sent in `if` but you can't get to print the result. Also, if you had a normal request somewhere and then first `if` doesn't work, you'll print your last result - you have to indent this.

```
with open('xyz.csv', mode='r', newline='') as csvFile :
    reader= csv.reader(csvFile)

    for col in reader:
        if col[2].upper() == "Y" and col[9].upper() == "Y":
            r = requests.get(col[6],headers=headers)
            resp = json.loads(resp)
            if resp.status_code == 200: #normal if and indent
                print(resp.content) #indented as well
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\C00264\PycharmProjects\API_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 387, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'url': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://url?

Comment: my url is in col[6] in csv file , how can i correct this syntax to run api from csv :

Comment: r = requests.get(col[6],headers=headers)

Comment: Is it really in col[6] or in 6th column? 6th column has index 5. Have you tried printing your line? My answer only corrected "no response data is found in terminal on run", you said nothing about the error before, so I assumed the rest of the code worked, only printing didn't enter.